# What are the effects of setting estimatedRowHeight in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

It seems that whatever I set in estimatedRowHeight, there isn't any visual differences.  Performance wise, I'm not sure how setting a value such as 1 vs 100 makes any difference.  The document just says setting a non-negative will give you a better performance, but doesn't elaborate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform its full initial internal layout and thus paint the scroll indicators correctly, the table view must know the heights of all the rows (as well as any section headers etc.).

By supplying the `estimatedRowHeight`, you allow the table to perform a full initial internal layout knowing only the heights of the *visible* rows (because it uses the estimated height for all the other rows). For a table view with variable row heights, that's much, much faster.

(Of course there is no point to the `estimatedRowHeight` if the table view's `rowHeight` is in fact the height of every row.)

Comment: So testing the effect of setting the `estimatedRowHeight` would involve scrolling, right?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Yes and no. You certainly might see the scroll indicators jump a little as more real row height information comes in and the table view changes its internal layout. But you can also see the effects up front if you know how to look. For example, `heightForRow` isn't queried up front for all rows, only for the visible rows.

Comment: So you're basically saying the `estimatedRowHeight` affects the scroll indicators. Does it also affect the scrollable height of the table view?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Of course. That's what the scroll indicators indicate!